# terraform deletes old instance template automatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have an issue where every time I create a new instance template, terraform auto deletes the previous instance I created. This occurs even if auto_delete = false and the name is different. My Code is located below.

```
    // Create instance template (replace with created image)
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "default" {
  name        = "appserver-template-020103"
  description = "This template is used to create app server instances."

  tags = ["foo", "bar"]

  labels = {
    environment = "dev"
  }

  instance_description = "description assigned to instances"
  machine_type         = "f1-micro"
  can_ip_forward       = false

  scheduling {
    automatic_restart   = true
    on_host_maintenance = "MIGRATE"
  }

  // Create a new boot disk from an image
  disk {
    source_image = "ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20180126"
    auto_delete  = false
    boot         = false
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
  }

  metadata {
    foo = "bar"
  }

  service_account {
    scopes = ["userinfo-email", "compute-ro", "storage-ro"]
  }
}
```

Comment: that's the feature in terraform, if you need second resource, create a new resource code

Comment: Thank you, I did not think of that. I changed "default" to "template-022201" which adds a date stamp to the resource. each new template created i change the date or, if in the same day, the instance count by 1.